# Rails 4.2 Integration Tests - Is there any way to reuse test code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing

If I start off with a test that checks the user can login:

```
test "can login successfully" do
  get "/session/new"
  assert_select "h1", "Log in to the Portal"
  assert_response :success
  post "/session", { username: "nick1", password: "password1" }
  assert_response :redirect
  follow_redirect!
  assert_select "h1", "Welcome to the Portal"
end
```

And in the rest of my tests, I want to test things that depend on the user to being logged in - I obviously don't want to be copying the above code into every test that requires the user to be logged in.

In my case, simulating a logged in user is simply a case of setting a `session[:user_id]` so I had a look around at setting session data inside the test but it appears to be very tricky. This leads me to think that maybe I could put the above code in some kind of re-usable function and call it from any test that needs a logged in user.

Does this sound like the right approach? if not, how is this problem normally solved?

Comment: *"Is there any way to reuse [test] code?"* Yes. You move it into a method. Then you call that method from elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way to reuse test code?

Tests in minitest are just classes. Which means you can use both classical inheritance and parallel inheritance (module mixins).

### Classical inheritance

```
class MyApp::IntegrationTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  def sign_in(user)
    post "/session", user.attributes.slice(%w { username password })
  end
end

class FooTest < MyApp::IntegrationTest

  setup do
    @user = User.create(username: "nick1", password: "password1")
    sign_in @user
  end

  test "can wozzle the fozzle" do
    # ...
  end
end
```

### Mixins:

```
module AuthenticationTestHelper
  def sign_in(user)
    post "/session", user.attributes.slice(%w { username password })
  end
end

class FooTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  include AuthenticationTestHelper

  setup do
    @user = User.create(username: "nick1", password: "password1")
    sign_in @user
  end

  test "can wozzle the fozzle" do
    # ...
  end
end
```

If you're using [Warden](https://github.com/hassox/warden) you can just include `Warden::Test::Helpers` - if you're not you probably should be instead of reinventing the authentication wheel.